# UTF8 string variable in c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, utf-8

I am using PostgreSQL to power a C# desktop application. When I use the *PgAdmin* query analyzer to update a text column with a special character (like the copyrights trademarks) it works pefectly:

```sql
update table1 set column1='value with special character ©' where column2=1
```

When I use this same query from my C# application, it throws an error:

> invalid byte sequence for encoding

After researching this issue, I understand that .NET strings use the UTF-16 Unicode encoding.

Consider:

```
string sourcetext = "value with special character ©";
// Convert a string to utf-8 bytes.
byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourcetext);

// Convert utf-8 bytes to a string. 
string desttext = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

The problem here is both the `sourcetext` and `desttext` are encoded as UTF-16 strings. When I pass `desttext`, I still get the exception.

I've also tried the following without success:

```
Encoder.GetString, BitConverter.GetString
```

**Edit**: I even tried this and doesn't help:

```
unsafe
{
  String utfeightstring = null;
  string sourcetext = "value with special character ©";
  Console.WriteLine(sourcetext);
  // Convert a string to utf-8 bytes. 
  sbyte[] utf8Chars = (sbyte[]) (Array) System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourcetext); 
  UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);

  // Instruct the Garbage Collector not to move the memory
  fixed (sbyte* pUtf8Chars = utf8Chars)
  {
    utfeightstring = new String(pUtf8Chars, 0, utf8Chars.Length, encoding);
  }
  Console.WriteLine("The UTF8 String is " + utfeightstring); 
}
```

Is there a datatype in .NET that supports storing UTF-8 encoded string? Are there alternative ways to handle this situation?

Comment: May be foolish question to you. but why not just use  System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])

Comment: As I explained encoder.getstring is not working either. By the way there is no such function available system.text.encoding.getstring.

Comment: No I am suggesting you to use  System.Text.Encoding.GetString not  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Comment: Is there a function System.Text.Encoding.GetString available in .NET 4.0? am I missing something here. It gives compilation error.

Comment: Yes here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc if not this please use Encoding.Convert method

Comment: @HatSoft getstring is not a static method. you cannot use system.text.encoding.getstring. you need to instantiate encoding class with any of its child class ut8encoding or asciiencoding then use that object.getstring. Again that is exactly what I mention in my question. which is not working.

Comment: Regarding encoding.convert it will give byte array. When I convert the byte array to string then the string becomes UTF16

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you misconfigured your database adapter to use a wrong encoding (ANSI or so)

Comment: @CodeInChaos thanks for the useful tip. could you please explain how to reset my database adapter to use utf8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per this page from the mono project [PostgreSQL](http://www.mono-project.com/PostgreSQL) they suggest that if you have errors with UTF8 strings that you can set the encoding to unicode in the connection string (if you are using the Npgsql driver):

> Encoding:  Encoding to be used. Possible values: ASCII(default) and UNICODE. Use UNICODE if you are getting problems with UTF-8 values:    Encoding=UNICODE

And I have been looking in the official Npgsql docs and it isn't mentioned.
[NpgsqlConnection.ConnectionString](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.ConnectionString.html)

Comment: Why would they use ASCII as default -_-

Comment: Thanks Peter, this seems will work. I'll check and accept this as answer if it does

Comment: @Esen Well I have never used postgresql so I have no idea if this will really fix your issue - but it does seem reasonable.

Comment: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20350&p=66796&hilit=utf8+encoding+postgresql#p66796 this link is also talking similar. I am trying to set unicode=true in web.config and see if that works. Any ways your answer showed me a path to move on.

Comment: Yes it works. I have to set Unicode=true in the connection string. Thanks to peter for his help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you give me an example? When I use `Encoding=UNICODE` or `Unicode=true` i get the following exception "Keyword not supported: unicode
Parametername: keyword".

Answer (score -1):

I think it may not cause by utf-8 or 16 ,it may cause by de special character,you can replace the char with entity char which like '&amp';

Comment: I narrowed down the issue. This query works in query analyzer and not through code. can you please explain. update table1 set column1='©' where column2=1

Answer (score -1):

Just put in your ConnectionString on the end a "...... ;Unicode=true"

Comment: I already figured out the answer, commented it at Peter M answer. Why are you duplicating that again.