# npgsql: reading strings doesn't seem to consider code page?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, npgsql, codepages

Firstly, I'm a complete n00b in both SQL and also have little experience with different code pages, so the answer may be quite simple, which would also explain why nobody here seems to have asked this before.

I have a PostgreSQL database (v 8.4.22, protocol v3) and a Unity3D application with npgsql 2.0. Now, I connect to my database, execute an NpgsqlCommand with ExecuteReader(), getting me an NpgsqlDataReader. Now, if I read from that with GetString( int ), I get a string with wrong encoding, my special characters are completely messed up, e.g. I get a 'Ã¶' instead 'ö'. I see this already in the debugger, so there is no issue with the output, the string returned is already messed up, so I don't really know what my options are at this point. The database is using UTF-8. The Data type of the column is 'text'.

Btw, I'm connecting without specifying the code page, since I read this is obsolete in the connection string since some PSQL version. Anyways, I tried, it didn't have any effect.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "codepages" are relevant here, the problem seems to be:

- the PostgreSQL database contains unicode, encoded as UTF-8, while...
- the npgsql interprets the data as ascii.

According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434073/utf8-string-variable-in-c-sharp) the solution is to explicitly specify `Encoding=UNICODE` in the connection string.

Comment: Codepages are basically the pre-unicode way of encoding different sets of characters. If you can get all your components to talk unicode, you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: Wow. I knew there was an easy solution to this. I wasn't able to find this in neither the npgsql docu nor the PostgreSQL docu. Just different, inconsistent parameter names from different sources, such as "CharSet", "character_set", "CharacterSet", etc., which were always set to "utf-8" but not "Encoding=UNICODE". Big THANKS!!